# Filter out a nestled key value

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
const data =  {
"supportPaneltext": [{
        "brand": "BMW",
        "paragraphList": [{
            "rowList": [
                "Europe, Middle East, Africa, Asia, Pacific"
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "brand": "Mercedez",
        "paragraphList": [{
                "rowList": [
                    "Europe, Middle East, Africa, Asia, Pacific"
                ]
            }]
    }]
}
```

I want to filter out the "brand" value to an array. The result would look like: `["BMW", Mercedez"]`

I have tried to filter out by:

```
Object.values(data).filter((item) => item.brand)
```

Without luck, What do I miss?

Comment: Why `filter()`? As the name suggests (and the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) explains) `.filter()` returns elements from an array that fulfill a supplied predicate. Have a look at `.map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` on your `supportPaneltext`

```
let result = data.supportPaneltext.map(a => a.brand);
```

```js
const data = {
  "supportPaneltext": [{
      "brand": "BMW",
      "paragraphList": [{
        "rowList": [
          "Europe, Middle East, Africa, Asia, Pacific"
        ]
      }]
    },
    {
      "brand": "Mercedez",
      "paragraphList": [{
        "rowList": [
          "Europe, Middle East, Africa, Asia, Pacific"
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
}

let result = data.supportPaneltext.map(a => a.brand);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: As already explained in the [duplicates here on SO](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=javascript+array+of+objects+extract+property+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ia=web)